# Is there any complete guide to the building and installation of ITK 4.0?

Tags: python, linux, build, installation, itk

I want to use the python bindings with the ITK 4.0. Is there any complete guide that how to build and install and correctly set the options for the wrappers? I am using Linux 11.04.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sept, 30, 2011 : WARNING  ITKv4 is still in beta and is under VERY active development.  Please do not take the current state of documentation as reflective of the process that will be available in the final version.

Comment: @Hans... When is it going to release finally???

Answer (score 2):

http://www.itk.org/Wiki/ITK_Release_4/Wrapping/WrapITK_Installation

Answer (score 0):

Did you have a look in this one? --> http://www.itk.org/Doxygen/html/index.html

Answer (score 0):

I've just written a concise tutorial on this:
https://pythonhosted.org/MedPy/installation/itkwrapper4.7.html

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this link answers the question?

https://itk.org/Wiki/ITK/Release_4/Wrapping/BuildProcess